# javascript websocket doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket

i actually have a problem with my websocket chat building here is the problem :

```
$('#datasend').click(function() {
    socket.emit('sendchat', {message: 'Hello'});
    $('#data').val('');
    $('#data').focus();
});
```

the script here just block at socket.emit...
but if i set the script in other order

```
$('#datasend').click(function() {
    $('#data').val('');
    $('#data').focus();
    socket.emit('sendchat', {message: 'Hello'});
});
```

here the 2 first line work but same problem block at socket.emit, i have try the same socket.emit line without be called by javascript with click and it work perfectly.

I don't know why but when i call the function by pushing my input button named #datasend it doesn't work !

thx for answering me!

Comment: Where is your `socket` variable defined?  Are you including the `socket.io` library?  Are you initializing the library and connecting to your server?  Are there any script errors showing in the console?  It sounds like you probably have a script error on the line: `socket.emit('sendchat', {message: 'Hello'});` which stops execution of the click handler because of the error.  Please look in your error console and see what error is being reported.

Comment: My socket is initialized in the client.js  

    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1337');  

  i have no error in the console this is the problem, here si my sendchat method it's only a print log but he doesnt work when called by the click  

        socket.on('sendchat', function(data){
  console.log('client send the message : ' + data.send_message);
 });